# How to show address bar in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

How to show address bar in WebBrowser control in a Windows Form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I could be mistaken but I don't believe the WebBrowserControl includes the address bar, toolbar, etc. I believe you'll have to create your own address bar. You could use the `Navigated` or `Navigating` events to determine when the URL is changing and update the text box.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
    }
}

private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text != e.Url.ToString())
    {
        textBox1.Text = e.Url.ToString();
    }
}
```

Edit: My form has a `TextBox` named textBox1, a `Button` named button1 and a `WebBrowserControl` named webBrowser1

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. Don't forget to select an answer if your question is solved.

Comment: Also am looking an option on how to add status bar and show the same for webbrowser control, any thoughts on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a textbox and then fill it with the site property i think

Comment: Thanks, pls. give me some more idea..may be with sample code on how to approach.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop a  text box into your form.
Use the URL.ToString method to set the textbox .text value to that url string:

```
Dim strURL As String
        strURL = ""

        If Me.TextBox1.Text.Length = 0 Then
            Me.TextBox1.Focus()
            Me.TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Red
        Else
            If InStr(Me.TextBox1.Text, "http://") = 0 Then
                strURL = "http://" & Me.TextBox1.Text.ToString()
            Else
                strURL = Me.TextBox1.Text.ToString()
            End If
            Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate(New System.Uri(strURL))
            Me.TextBox1.Text = Me.WebBrowser1.Url.ToString()
        End If
```

Here's C#:

```
string strURL = null; 
    strURL = ""; 

    if (this.TextBox1.Text.Length == 0) { 
        this.TextBox1.Focus(); 
        this.TextBox1.BackColor = Color.Red; 
    } 
    else { 
        if (Strings.InStr(this.TextBox1.Text, "http://") == 0) { 
            strURL = "http://" + this.TextBox1.Text.ToString(); 
        } 
        else { 
            strURL = this.TextBox1.Text.ToString(); 
        } 
        this.WebBrowser1.Navigate(new System.Uri(strURL)); 
        this.TextBox1.Text = this.WebBrowser1.Url.ToString(); 
    }
```

Comment: I know it's translatable but the OP is asking for C#.

Comment: Thanks JonH, looks very helpful.