# Get new URL of WebBrowser in WPF

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oauth-2.0, webbrowser-control

Is there anyway to get the current URL of a WebBrowser?  I have an application where I'm trying to obtain an authorization code for an API after a user logs in and is redirected to another Url where they are required to press a button that authenticates the system.  After doing so, the user is then redirected to http://localhost/?code={authorization_code}.  I have no control over that flow, but I'm wondering if it's possible to get that url after being redirected so many times. I've tried using GET and POST methods, but even in POSTMAN, it still required the links to pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best solution, but I ended up solving this by adding an address bar to display the URL for the redirected page and read from that textbox.

[How to show address bar in WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923740/how-to-show-address-bar-in-webbrowser-control)