# Open customized external web browser with .NetStandard

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, .net-core, .net-standard-2.0

We need to be able to open a web browser from within our application (.NetStandard 2.0). The browser should be opened as an external application, the requirement does not call for the browser to be embedded in our application, thus using the WebBroswer control is not an option. We need to be able to specify the following options:

- Height of the browser
- Width of the browser
- Top position
- Left position
- Addressbar enabled or disabled
- Menubar enabled or disabled
- Statusbar enabled or disabled
- Toolbar enabled or disabled

We initially thought that using the Process class would work, but it doesn't seem that these options can be specified with the Process class. Any articles or recommendations as to how we can achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which browser are you targeting? Most browsers feature some kind of "kiosk mode" which can be controlled via command line arguments.

Comment: IE, as far as I understand we'll be targeting different versions depending what the client has installed on their machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You could consider creating a Windows Form application or [WPF application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/getting-started/walkthrough-my-first-wpf-desktop-application), then use the [WebBrowser control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-windows-forms) to display the web page.</s>

More detail information about using WebBrowser control, please check the following links:

[WebBrowser Control Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-overview)

[How to: Add Web Browser Capabilities to a Windows Forms Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-add-web-browser-capabilities-to-a-windows-forms-application)

[How to show address bar in WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923740/how-to-show-address-bar-in-webbrowser-control)

[WebBrowser Control In WPF](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/webbrowser-control-in-wpf/)

Try to use the [InternetExplorer object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752084(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to control an instance of Windows Internet Explorer.

First, right click the application **Reference** and select **Add Reference** option, then in the **COM** tab, checked the **Microsoft Internet Controls** and click **OK** to add reference.

[image]

Then, refer to the following code to use InternetExplorer object:

```
        SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
        ie.Navigate("http://www.bing.com");
        ie.ToolBar = 0; //hide or display the toolbar.
        ie.AddressBar = false; //hide or display the AddressBar.
        ie.Left = 200;
        ie.Height = 800;
        ie.Width = 500;
        ie.StatusBar = false; // hide or display the statusBar.
        ie.Visible = true; //display IE browser.
```

More detail information about the properties, please check the [IWebBrowser2 interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752127(v%3Dvs.85)).

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions and the useful links! Unfortunately I found out that the requirement is for the browser to be opened as an external application and not embedded in the application :/. I'll edit my original question to make this clear.

Comment: @BabyDoll, I have modified the reply, please check it and use the InternetExplorer object.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I ended up having to import the SHDocVw.dll using tlbimp. Works beautifully!